# Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module usando Jest con Vite

Tags: reactjs, typescript, test, jest, vite

Estoy usando vite en mi proyecto con react-ts y a la hora de ejecutar un test me ha saltado el siguiente error:

```
 baseURL: import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL,
                  ^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module
```

No puedo usar el `process.env` ya que uso vite, pero el test no me pilla el `import.meta`
El test tiene la siguiente estructura, pero el problema está en que el `import.meta` no funciona:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';

import ButtonComponent from './ButtonComponent';

test('render button content', () => {
    const component = render(<ButtonComponent quantity={quantity} data={undefined} from="XXX"/>);
    const button = component.getByTestId('button');

    expect(component).toBeTruthy();

    expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(component.getByText(/serial/i));
});
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puedo hacer para que jest (react-testing-library) me funcione bien con vite?

Comment: Puede que [esto](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12183#issuecomment-1004320665) te ayude. Puedes checar también [estas posibles soluciones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961387/how-to-use-import-meta-when-testing-with-jest).

Comment: La cosa es que no tengo ningun jest.config.js ni nada de eso, solo un vite.config.ts

Comment: Te dejo este gist con la configuración [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://gist.github.com/AlexAlonsoMontero/981815de517902322f7a1c6b7bae9baf) Pero lo de las variables de entorno no funciona, creo que la única solución es pasar a vitest, pero aún así, estoy buscando, si encuentro algo te digo

Comment: Lo mejor que he aprendido luego de prueba y error con varios de estas formas con babel config o vite config o usando dotenv es que lo mejor es crear un archivo con las .env vars y luego hacer un mock de este en el test. Esta es la forma más fácil sin hacer configuraciones raras ni instalar ningún paquete extra https://stackoverflow.com/a/74882007/17638569

Answer (score 2):

Con esto te tendría que funcionar.

Creamos un fichero, yo lo creo en una carpeta helpers con el siguiente código. (Nombre del fichero getEnviroments.js)
**getEnviroments.js**

```
export const getEnviroments = () =>{
import.meta.env;
return {
    ...import.meta.env
}
```

}

En el fichero jest.setup.js ( es posible que sea necesario instalar dotenv )
jest.setup.js

```
require('dotenv').config({
    path: '.env'
})

jest.mock('./src/helpers/getEnviroments',()=>({
    getEnviroments: () => ({...process.env})
}))
```

Ya podemos usar en los ficheros test process.env

Dejo enlace al Gist con toda la configuración de React Testing Library con Vite https://gist.github.com/AlexAlonsoMontero/981815de517902322f7a1c6b7bae9baf

Comment: Debería estar marcada como solución!